# What's the correct way to handle promise rejections so that the function exits?

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise

Let's say that I have this code:

```
function doSomething() {
    const foo = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        //...
        reject();
    }).catch(error => {
        //I'd like to exit the doSomething function since the promise rejected
        return;//This only exists the this arrow funtion
    });

    console.log('Should not get to here if foo rejects');
}
```

If `foo` returns a rejected promise, then I'd like to exit `doSomething()`, but the code above does not do this. Instead since the `error` is caught, the code continues.

If I do not `catch` the rejected promise then I get an error: `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning`:

```
function doSomething() {
    const foo = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        //...
        reject();
    });
    console.log('Should not get to here if foo rejects');
}
```

I know that I can do this, but this just feels messy:

```
function doSomething() {
    let exitFunction = false;
    const foo = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        //...
        reject();
    }).catch(error => {
        //I'd like to exit the doSomething function since the promise rejected
        exitFunction = true;
    });

    if (exitFunction) {
       return;
    }

    console.log('Should not get to here if foo rejects');
}
```

So what is the best way to handle something like this? It'd be nice to be able to do this:

```
function doSomething() {
    const foo = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        //...
        reject();
    });
    if (foo.rejected) {
        return;
    }
    console.log('Should not get to here if foo rejects');
}
```

Or even this:

```
function doSomething() {
    const foo = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        //...
        reject();
    }).catch(error => {
        return function2;//Sort of like JS's `break loop2;`
    });
    console.log('Should not get to here if foo rejects');
}
```

Does anyone else feel my pain, if so what are is the best (cleanest) way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using `try/catch` if you handle promises in `async function`

```js
function promiseFunc() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    //...
    reject("error!");
  });
}

async function doSomething() {
  try {
    const foo = await promiseFunc();
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return;
  }

  console.log("Should not get to here if foo rejects");
}

doSomething();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you just misunderstand where the `return` is returning to
in first code
the `return` is return to `foo`
that's why it keep going

you can just use foo to catch return result like this

```js
async function doSomething() {
    let foo = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        reject();
    }).catch(error => {
        return false;
    });
    if(!foo) return console.log("rejected and stopped");
    console.log('Should not get to here if foo rejects');
}
doSomething()
```

or like this

```js
async function doSomething() {
    if (!
        await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            reject();
        }).catch(error => {
            return false;
        })
    ) return console.log("rejected and stopped");;
    console.log('Should not get to here if foo rejects');
}
doSomething()
```